# Is it ok to assign $this to another object loaded from memcache?

Tags: php, oop, memcached

Is it fine to assign $this to another object loaded from memcache in the constructor? 
I am mainly worried about performance and memory.

I was thinking something like this:

```
function __construct($userid){
   global $memcachedvar;

   if($userobject = $memcachedvar->get($userid){
      $this = $userobject;
   } 
}
```

Is this a bad design pattern?

Comment: PHP forbids reassignment of `$this` anywhere in an object; your code will trigger a fatal error. By the time the constructor is invoked, memory would have been allocated for a brand new object and it'd be inappropriate (according to the engine anyway) to swap it out for another one.

Comment: Object itself shouldn't be responsible for caching. If you need such functionality - add another layer which will instantiate new object or retrieve one from mcd.

Comment: @BoltClock and @zerkms thanks! I will create a wrapper to call recover objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not OK. It is, in fact, invalid.

`$this` is magical and may not be re-assigned.

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> PHP forbids reassignment of `$this` anywhere in an object; your code will trigger a fatal error. By the time the constructor is invoked, memory would have been allocated for a brand new object and it'd be inappropriate (according to the engine anyway) to swap it out for another one. - [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026099/is-it-ok-to-assign-this-to-another-object-loaded-from-memcache/6036476#comment6967087_6026099)
>
> Object itself shouldn't be responsible for caching. If you need such functionality - add another layer which will instantiate new object or retrieve one from mcd. - [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026099/is-it-ok-to-assign-this-to-another-object-loaded-from-memcache/6036476#comment6967104_6026099)

@BoltClock and @zerkms give great comments. Clearly this constructor is not really possible.